# binding a usercontrol inside of a ListBox dataTemplate control silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, listbox

I have a user control as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaseDatabase.Controls.SearchResultControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="192" d:DesignWidth="433">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="230" Width="419">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="68*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleLink" Height="33" Text="{Binding CaseTitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Foreground="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

with a dependency property for CaseTitle:

```
public string CaseTitle
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { 
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Title.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CaseTitle", typeof(string), typeof(SearchResultControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(SearchResultControl.OnValueChanged)));
```

in my .xaml page I have a listbox and inside its datatemplate I instanciate my control. This listbox's ItemsSource is binding to a domain Service. I know the binding works and I get the appropiate number of elemets but no data is displayed whatsoever.

the code for my listbox is the following:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="SearchResultsList" Width="Auto" MinHeight="640" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SearchDomainDataSource, Path=Data}"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="158" Width="400">
                    <my:SearchResultControl CaseTitle="{Binding Path=Title}" /> 
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

So can anybody suggest how am I messing up my binding to my user control? Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `{Binding CaseTitle}` isn't finding the `CaseTitle` dependency property you created.  The default `Source` object that a Binding uses is the current value of `DataContext` property of the element to which it is bound.  That object is not the `UserControl`.

You therefore need to change that binding as follows:-

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TitleLink" Height="33" Text="{Binding Parent.CaseTitle, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Now the source object of the binding becomes the `Grid` with the name "LayoutRoot" which is the direct child of the `UserControl`, hence its `Parent` property is the user control and from there you can bind to the `CaseTitle` property.